# neo4j node id's and relationships

Tags: neo4j

I'm relatively new to node, but went through the training tutorial and have been working heavily with it the past couple of weeks. My question is with regards to node id's and relationships.

I noticed that whenever I query Neo4j, the resultset never returns the node id's, is this on purpose? The reason I ask is when I try to relate records, I'm having to rely on other attributes to fetch the nodes in my MATCH clause so that I can later use them to build the relation.

After exhausting google, and noticing that the neo4j training tutorials never make use of the node id for anything and instead rely on other identifiers (e.g. movie title, actor name, etc), I've come to the conclusion/realization that perhaps this is by design, and it's the responsibility of the DBA to define his own identifiers (and index them) and not rely on the neo4j node id.

Am I correct in my assumptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j does send back its node identifiers. If you want to explicitly fetch them in a `RETURN` clause, you can use `id(your_node_alias)`. When a node gets deleted, its identifier can be re-used for another new node. Therefore it's never a good idea to rely on them. Creating and indexing your own unique identifier property is always a good idea.

Comment: thank you, I'll stick to my own identifiers if that's considered best practice :)

Comment: any idea on Spring data neo4j 6.1.1 where i can use UUID string in Node identifier repository and not in the case of Relationship if i do so it throws error as follows: `The target class <className> for the properties of the relationship RELATIONSHIP_LABEL is missing a property for the generated, internal ID (@Id @GeneratedValue Long id) which is needed for safely updating properties`

 where the relationship identifier only accepts the Long value. @tstorms